# Kinetic.js : Error (Object [object Object] has no method 'setAnimation')

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a sprite which has name property.

I want to find that sprite during run time and then change the animation of that.

I tried this :-

```
myKineticGroup.find('.myspriteName').setAnimation('set_new_animation');
```

I got following error : (Object [object Object] has no method 'setAnimation').

I typed this myKineticGroup.find('.myspriteName') in my console, there i am getting the sprite object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "myspriteName" element is an shape or blob, give it an ID and you can access it after. Like this:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 300,
        y: 90,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'green',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        offset: {
          x: 50,
          y: 25
        },
        draggable: true,
        id: 'myspriteName'
      });

stage.find('#myspriteName')[0].setAnimation('set_new_animation');
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the sprite by its name we can use this:

```
stage.find('.myspriteName')[0].setAnimation('set_new_animation');
```